# Trying to set a minimum value to input

Tags: php, mysql, math

I am calculating the decrease in an increase which works perfect, the issue is that at around the value of 94-95 it stop updating. So i ofcourse had to set a value to input if the user reached +0. So i thought i would write `$increase = max(0.2, $increment);` so i takes 0.2 as the increase if the other value is below that. So there alway can be an increase.

The issue that is it wont increase by 0.2 when the user reaches a high enough value that the algoritm before will increase the value. So i tried set it to 0.2 when the increase is below 0.2. But it doesnt add anything, although if i change the 0.2 to 1 it updates with 1.

Here is my code so you can understand it better.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $currentStrength = $row["strength"];
        $increment = (1 - ($currentStrength - 18) * 0.01) * 2;
        $increase = max(0.2, $increment);
        $StrengthValue = $increase + $currentStrength;
    }

    $sql = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE stats SET strength=(strength + $increase) WHERE username=:username");
```

Comment: Hi there, what's the question here?

Comment: @Progrock Sorry i totally missed actually express that the question here was. Edited thanks.

Comment: What field/column type is `stats.strength`?

Comment: @Progrock INT 255

Comment: @Progrock oh really, what would i need to change it to for this to work?

Comment: Your integer column will only allow integers.  You'll have to change the field type to accommodate fractions.  Check mysql reference for numeric types.